# Keep track of how much I type

Tags: windows, statistics, keyboard

I am looking for a piece of software that will keep track of how many characters I type throughout the day.

The obvious thing that comes to mind is a keylogger, but honestly I don't feel safe using a keylogger and doubt that it will have exactly what I am looking for.

I just want to be able to open up the program and see that I've typed 200,000 characters, or however many I've typed since I last reset the counter. I am looking for something that is relatively simple, but gets the job done. I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [WhatPulse](http://www.whatpulse.org/):

- Most features are free
- Windows/Mac/Linux
- Stats are [available online](http://www.whatpulse.org/Franck.Dernoncourt#apps) as well as on the desktop client (from which you can export them as CSV).
- Support several computers
- It records the number of keystrokes per application:

[image: WhatPulse UI]

- Keyboard heatmap:

[image: Keyboard heatmap image]

Comment: Thankyou, this is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for!

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you are looking for then. [Keyboardtracer](http://keyboardtracer.com/) its quite simple interface and yeah you will be able to open up the program and can simple see the keypresses like this

[image: Like this]