# Google Chrome extension to keep track of how much time I spend composing text in Google Chrome

Tags: chrome, monitoring, keyboard

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension that can keep track of how much time I spend composing text in Google Chrome. Ideally, it should keep a log of how much time I spend for each composition as well as on which URL the composition was made.

Any price or license is fine.

I am aware of [Keep track of how much I type](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/25517/903) but it focuses on the number of keystrokes.

Comment: There are programs that keep track of how much time you spend on any task or program on the computer.  Perhaps that would suit your needs.  See https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/696/a-program-to-log-how-much-time-you-spend-in-what-program

Comment: @aparente001 thanks, in that question I was interested in a more fine-grained analysis of my use of Google Chrome.

Comment: Toggl Button seems to have strong reviews.  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/toggl-button-productivity/oejgccbfbmkkpaidnkphaiaecficdnfn